# HP Proliant Servers DL380 G3

Tags: mysql, database, shared-storage

I've bought 2 hp G3 servers with Smart Array 5I Storage Controller, how can I install the MYSQL on the array storage so that the linux on both server can read the DB, I'm kinda lost here.

This is what I need exactly, install linux on both G3 servers, and both of them need to be able to reach a shared DB, how can I do that?

Comment: is this for HA, or do you just need to *connect* to the database from both servers?

Answer (score 0):

While doing this is very easy I really have to suggest that you don't do it, unless you are talking about read-only databases. Having multiple instances of any database server working on the same set of files is a sure road to disaster. The sensible way is to create a master/slave or even master/master replication pair.

However, if you absolutely feel the urge to do this anyway just install the two instances as usual, then alter the configuration of one or both to point to the desired data directory.